# some error in using $push in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

my Schema is

```
var User = new mongoose.Schema({
    //general information
    name : {type:String},
    email : {type : String},
    number : {type : String},
    password : {type:String},
    //featured information
    path: { type: String},
    dob : {type:String},
    gender : {type : String},
    blood_group : {type:String},
    marital_status : {type : String}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user',User);
```

i want to use update some details by-

```
app.post('/contactinfo',function (req,res) {
    var name = req.body.name;
    var number = req.body.number;
    var email = req.body.email;
    User.update({_id : userID},{
        $push : {
            name : name,
            number : number,
            email : email
        }
    },{new : true },function (err,result) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            console.log(result);
            res.send({status : "success" , message : "Details updates"});
        }
    });
});
```

I don't define array anywhere

but the problem is that is show error on updating

```
{ MongoError: The field 'name' must be an array but is of type string in document {_id: ObjectId('5a0880e2d767e8131807e7f4')}
```

I am stuck here

please someone help me in solving this error

Comment: if i use $set then all other field will remove...

Comment: thnx , it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to change your `$push` to `$set`. That's it.

Comment: well said but  previously when i was using $push it works well.

Comment: you can use $push when you want to push an item into an array. If you want to use $push you might change your model.